# How add "responsive" width for email newsletter?

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, html-email, email-client

How add `width` to table in my newsletter and have it responsive for all email clients ?

**A**

```
style="width: 100%"
```

**B**

```
style="width: 300px"
```

**C**

```
 width="300"
```

**D**

```
 width="300px"
```

**E**

```
 width="100%"
```

Comment: Do you want 100% width or 300px?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour i read that 100% maybe did problems... So if isn't true is better have 100% but if is a problem i will use 300px

Comment: Keep in mind, it doesn't have to be responsive design to be mobile email client friendly, but regardless A will be my choice.

Answer (score 3):

To cover **ALL** email clients, including desktop Outlook and mobile Gmail, **you need a hybrid/spongy approach**:

```
<div style="max-width: 300px;">
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="300"><tr><td>
  <![endif]-->
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 300px;">
    /* email code */
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td></tr></table>
  <![endif]-->
</div>
```

At its core, it uses max-width and min-width to impose rigid baselines (allowing some movement) and imposes a fixed, wide width for Outlook who is shackled to desktop anyway. Once a mobile-friendly baseline is set, media queries progressively enhance the email further in clients that support it.

It's pretty verbose and essentially requires two sets of markup (one for desktop Outlook and one for everyone else), but this approach will get you total coverage in the major email clients.

[This template](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-fluid.html) shows a basic version of this code in action.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `style` instead of `width` attribute as it is deprecated in HTML5
2. I suggest 100% width and max-width together in style because it is not comfortable to find the next line in a screen wider than 960px.

   ```
   <div style="width:100%;max-width:960px;">your content here</div>
   ```

Comment: hmm... And you say that works for all email clients ? (Also if added to table tag)

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in Desktop Outlook because it [doesn't support `max-width`](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).