# responsive width for HMTL email - 2023

Tags: html, email, responsive, markup

I would like to make a responsive email template with a maximum width.

I found a very helpful post here:

[How add "responsive" width for email newsletter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556541/how-add-responsive-width-for-email-newsletter)

But I am wondering if it is still applicable in 2023, particularly with regards to lack of support for max-width in Outlook desktop.

Is the hybrid/spongy approach still necessary?